# exit(0) function shows up an error

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c

So I have been trying to write a code where I use the `millis()` function to print the milliseconds of on-time of the board using `Serial`. But the condition is I want to stop printing the value once it reaches 10 seconds (10000ms).

I have been trying to use the `exit()` function but I get no output then.

```
#include<stdlib.h>

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial


}

void loop()

{

unsigned long timer1;

while(timer1%10000!=0)

{

timer1=millis();

Serial.println(timer1);

}

    exit(1);

}
```

Comment: What do you imagine `exit()` is supposed to do in an embedded system?

Comment: exit() is probably a bad idea in a bare-metal embedded system unless you know for a fact how the environment will respond.  Consider either an infinite `while(1);` loop explicit in your own code, or shutting down the processor.  Make sure to wait until the serial output buffer is empty before shutting down or disabling interrupts, or you may see your messages truncated.

Comment: Where do you suppose `exit()` would exit *to* in a microcontroller? Your desk?

Answer (score 2):

The AVR library documentation for [exit()](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1ga137096a48cc0c731052cadfb69c39b34.html) is great help. It explains that the interrupts are turned off and an infinite loop is entered. As the interrupts get turned off the last characters in the Serial buffer are not transmitted.

You can use [Serial.flush()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) to wait for the transmission to complete before calling exit().

Cheers!